# Convert an input stream to a double vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, stringstream

I am having issues getting an input line of comma-delimited numbers to properly pass into a double vector.

I'm mildly new to C++ and am in a bit of a pickle. I've tried using a double array, but double vectors seem to work better.

```
int main(){
    vector<double> vect;
    string input1;
    string token;
    int i;
    int size;
    cout << "Please input up to 1000 comma-delimited numbers (I.E. '5,4,7.2,5'): ";
    cin >> input1;
    stringstream ss(input1);


    while (ss >> i){
        vect.push_back(i);
        if (ss.peek() == ','){
            ss.ignore();
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++){
        cout << vect.at(j) << ", ";
    }

}
```

The whole numbers seem to pass fine, but if I include a decimal (I.E. 1.4), the decimal is not include. There are no error messages. How can I fix this?

Comment: also stream -> string -> string stream -> parsing is needlessly inefficient

Answer (score 1):

You are using an integer to read from `ss` (`int i;`). An integer cannot contain decimal points or fractions. Change it to `double` and you will be fine. Also `std::vector` is almost always preferrable over plain arrays.

Note that in your last for loop, you can also use the subscript operator to access the vector elements:

```
for (int j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++){
    cout << vect[j] << ", ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that. I have a habit of missing one minor detail and blowing up my project.